# How to deserealize a list of type interface with Newtonsoft.Json?

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to get a list of different classes that share the same interface deserialized. However, the following error appears:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Could not create an instance of type StudentHousingFramework.Interfaces.IAccount. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path '[0].tasksToDo', line 4, position 16.'

This is where the error occurs:

```
public List<IAccount> DeserealiseRoom(string list)
    {
        path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, list);
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            var file = File.ReadAllText(path);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<IAccount>>(file);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This is my serialization method:

```
public void Serealise<T>(string nameList, List<T> list)
        {
            path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, nameList);
            string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
            }); ;

            File.WriteAllText(path, jsonString);
        }
```

Here I'm trying to deserialize, for example, a list of the class `rooms` that happen to have an interface called `IAccount`.

Here is that class:

```
public class Room : IAccount
{
    public List<ITask> tasksToDo { 
        get
        {
            return factory.manager.tasks.FindAll(w => w.claimer == this);
        }
    }

    public Login login { get; set; }
    public bool isOccupied { get; private set; } = true;
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name
    {
        get
        {
            return "Room " + id;
        }
    }
    
    public Json json { get; set; } = new Json();
    private Factory factory { get; set; }

    public Room(Factory factory, int id)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
        this.id = id;
        login = new Login();
    }


}
```

Here is the interface:

```
public interface IAccount
{
    public Json json { get; set; }
    Login login { get; set; }
    int id { get; set; }
    string name { get;}
}
```

Is there anything that I can do to salvage this situation?

Comment: No offense, but have you tried searching "JSON.NET deserialize interface"? I can find number of possible solutions, none may apply to your case, but you should review them.

Comment: Since you are using `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto` in serialization step, use it in the deserialization as well.